Android MAUI App: GeneralSecurityException during Release Authentication but Works in Debug
I am developing a mobile application using .NET MAUI. Everything works perfectly in debug mode, but when I switch to the release mode and try to authenticate, I encounter the following error:
Exception_WasThrown Java.Security.GeneralSecurityException
Here are the details of my setup and what I've tried so far:
.NET MAUI application targeting net8.0-android.
Visual Studio 2022.
Using SecureStorage to store tokens.
Authentication with a backend service.
Verified permissions in AndroidManifest.xml.
Cleaned and rebuilt the project.
The error only occurs when the authentication is successful.
I am seeking assistance to understand why this issue occurs only in the release build and how to resolve it. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
[RelayCommand]
    private async Task Login()
    {
        try
        {
            var tokenResponse = await _authenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(PinGet!, PasswordGet!);
            if (tokenResponse == null)
            {
                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", "Authentication failed", "OK");
                return;
            }

            await SecureStorage.SetAsync("access_token", tokenResponse.JwtToken!);
            await SecureStorage.SetAsync("refresh_token", tokenResponse.RefreshToken!);

            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Success", "Logged in successfully", "OK");
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(HomePage));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", $"An error occurred: {ex.Message}", "OK");
        }
    }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="Mobile.Mobile">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/mainicon2" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:label="Mobile">
    </application>
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="34" />
</manifest>



If you disable this await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(HomePage)); do you get the same error?

I tried removing the lines of code where SecureStorage is used, and it redirected me to the page without any issues. So, I am 99% sure that the problem is related to storing data in SecureStorage.
@MustafaMutasim

From documentation, SecureStorage should save simple data, to confirm that please replace tokenResponse with simple text and test it

I tried what you suggested
await SecureStorage.SetAsync("simple_key", "simple_value");
However, I still received the same error. Additionally, I saw the following warnings during the build:
Optimizing assemblies for size may change the behavior of the app. Be sure to test after publishing. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink
Optimizing assemblies for size. This process might take a while.
Interestingly, the app worked perfectly in release mode about two weeks ago, and the authentication code has hardly changed since then. Now, this error occurs due to the use of SecureStorage.

Ok, disable those optimization with Project Properties on this Answer

I added the following lines of code to the project file:

false
false

After that, I received a different error during authentication:
javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException
After researching solutions, I found that disabling backups in the manifest file helps:
<application android:allowBackup="false" ... >
This increased the APK size, but now everything works correctly.
Thank you for your advice!

Glad it works, kindly post your answer to close this question.  Reduce | Questions with no answers

The issue was likely with SecureStorage. This problem appeared recently, although the code hasn't changed significantly.
Following the suggestions, I added these lines to the csproj:
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(Configuration)=='Release'">
    <RunAOTCompilation>false</RunAOTCompilation>
    <PublishTrimmed>false</PublishTrimmed>
</PropertyGroup>

Afterwards, during authentication, I encountered the: "javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException" error, which I resolved by disabling backups in the manifest:
<application android:allowBackup="false" ... >

These solutions helped fix the issues in the release application.
